# How might I do memory / processor usage checking by solaris zones

Tags: performance, monitoring, solaris

How might I do memory / processor usage checking by Solaris zones?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the following command:

`prstat -Z`

Comment: +1, but what about the zones which are part of a pool? Manual says that `prstat -Z` will give usage with respect to the pool. Is there any way to find with respect to the ncpus cap? Or is it practical to do so?